# In default latex-mode emacs $ character break color

Tags: emacs, latex

I need to include HTML code in LaTeX and I'm using the `listings` package for that.
The problem is that if there is a `$` character in my HTML code the color of the word after `$` is broken in Emacs. To get the correct color I need to use another `$`.

For example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    var mapElement = $("#map")[0];

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.720741,10.408413),
        zoom: 10
    };
\end{lstlisting}
```

After the `$` character the text in the rest of the document isn't highlighted correctly.
I'm not using AUCTeX but the default `latex-mode` of Emacs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to demonstrate the problem? Also, what version of Emacs are you using? On Emacs 24.3.50.1, I seem to get correct highlighting for the `\begin{lstlisting}`, `\end{lstlisting}` tag pair itself, and no highlighting at all for the JavaScript code inside the listings environment.

Comment: As to a current version of Emacs Trunk (GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2014-03-19 on MP.local), the code you provided highlights `\begin` and `\end` in a reddish-purplish color; and `1stlisting` is blue in both places -- the balance of code is the default black and Emacs has a white background.  This is with a blank `.emacs` (aka `init.el`) using `LaTeX mode defined in 'tex-mode.el'`.  Therefore, my first hunch / guess is that you have a custom font-lock definition somewhere in your user configuration file that is **not** in `tex-mode.el`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a nice work around at http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=25036

Use the following to output a `$` each time you type `4>` in the Latex code:

```
\lstset{
        literate={4>}{\$}1
}
```

then put your listing code in as normal

```
\begin{lstlisting}
  ruby -e "4>(curl -fsSL\ https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
\end{lstlisting}
```

which will work around highlighting issues and AucTeX will still look nice and pretty! (: